# Is there a more satisfactory answer than just saying that the manifold of special relativity is the $\mathbb R^4$/some set of "events"?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, maxwell-equations

I'm an undergraduate who visited a course on differential manifolds and now I have the task to reformulate the maxwell equations in terms of differential forms. The most obvious question that arises first is: On what manifold are the forms defined?

Unfortunately, it seems to be difficult to get good answers. Some people say Minkowski space is just the $\mathbb R^4$, others completely ignore this point. I know that there are a lot of related questions, but the answers are either not satisfactory (especially for a mathematician studying differential geometry) or contain too advanced maths for an undergraduate.

I assume that it is not easy (or even impossible) to give a definite answer, but I'd like to hear some  opinions on this. If you know of a reference where this is discussed in more detail, please let me know.

Comment: [This section of Wikipedia might be helpful?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Mathematical_structure)

Comment: Related question: [Maxwell's Equations using Differential Forms](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86510/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minkowski space time is a four dimensional **affine** space whose space of translations is equipped with an indefinite symmetric non-degenerate  metric with Lorentzian signature.

Every affine space has a natural smooth (real analytic) manifold structure induced by every arbitrarily fixed Cartesian coordinate system. That is the differentiable structure used in special relativity.

Cartesian coordinate systems associated to pseudo orthonormal bases are interpreted as coordinates at rest with inertial reference frames. Actually,

(1) one considers only basis whose temporal element is future oriented;

(2) two Cartesian systems related by means of a spatial 3-rotation or a space time translation or a combination of both are supposed to define the same inertial reference frame (inertial reference frame are equivalence classes).

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, I am happy that my guess turned out right (I have a supervisor for the talk about maxwell equations and when I asked him if the Minkowski space is an affine space, he told me that he didn't know what an affine space is).  I am not sure that I understand what you mean by a  cartesian coordinate system: I learned that if we consider an affine space $M$ equipped with an n-dimensional translation vector space $V$ a tuple $(O,P_1,...,P_n)\in M^{n+1}$ is called coordinate system if $(\vec{OP_1},...,\vec{OP_n})$ is a basis of $V$.

Comment: Is that the same definition you use? If yes, are cartesian coordinate systems special types of coordinate systems?

Comment: A Cartesian coordinate system is  the map associating each point $P$ of the space to the components of the unique vector joining a fixed origin $O$ with the point $P$. These are very special coordinate systems on the affine space. First of all because every Cartesian system is global: it completely covers the space and identify it with $R^n$.

Comment: Are you Italian as your nickname suggests?

Comment: To be precise, I am half italian :)

Comment: If you are able to read Italian you can consult my lecture notes on SR http://www.science.unitn.it/%7Emoretti/RelativitaSpeciale.pdf

Comment: However there are also **less elementary** English notes of mine http://www.science.unitn.it/%7Emoretti/tensori.pdf    and http://www.science.unitn.it/%7Emoretti/manifolds.pdf   which could be of some interest for you....Barring a number of typos and English mistakes ;)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your notes. I'm able to read Italian, so I'll check them all out.

Comment: I am currently reading your notes and I have a problem: In your notes about manifolds (example 2.11), you explain how to construct a topology and an atlas on an affine space. This means that if $M$ is an affine space and $O\in M$, the symbol $T_OM$ is well defined. However, on page 34 of your italian notes on special relativity (where you construct an affine structure on $M$) you define the translation space to be $T_OM$ for some $O\in M$. Since we don't have an affine structure yet, I don't understand what $T_OM$ is.

Comment: If I haven't missed something, could you please explain what $T_OM$ is in that context? (I guess this should be moved to chat.)

Comment: In my Italian lecture notes I assume that the reader is familiar with the standard notion of tangent space of a manifold. Here  $T_OM^4$ is exactly that notion. The spacetime $M^4$ is assumed to be a 4D differentiable manifold (see p. 9-10). I am there (p. 34) proving that Minkowski spacetime turns out to be an affine space where the space of translations is exactly the tangent space at a given event $O$ arbitrarily chosen.  The fact that

Comment: The fact that $M^4$ is a manifold is therefore assumed *a priori* in those Italian lecture notes of mine, so that I can exploit the standard mathematical technology of differentiable manifolds.  However, one can instead start from scratch with the assumption that the spacetime of Minkowski is an affine space without referring to general differential geometry. This alternative approach is adopted in  chapter 8 of  http://www.science.unitn.it/%7Emoretti/tensori.pdf

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up :) Are you considering to publish a book on the theory of relativity? If the notes on special relativity weren't in italian, merging the three lecture notes you linked and maybe reorganizing them a bit would already give a great book!

Comment: Thanks... Indeed, I am considering it. But I am quite busy and these notes should be completed by adding further material before passing to a publication. After all I have published a number of books and I should be content with them :). My next publication will be the English translation of my recent Italian  book on Analytical Mechanics...